# How to build a web page using different sections created in Craft

Tags: craft3, entries, php, sections, craft2

I am a beginner in Craft. I have a Craft website. There is an HTML design with me. From admin, I divided the HTML into sections and created entries based on that. All the coding related to each sections done.

My question is, from where we will combine these sections for creating a page on the website?

I want to replace some already existing sections with new sections created.
From which part I can find this one?

Comment: Rakhi, your question is very general. Can you describe your sections, what they contain, and if and how they are related? 

You will strongly benefit from this free tutorial: https://craftquest.io/courses/craft-cms-3-tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Actually, not all sections are created equal. Craft actually has three different types of sections:

1. Singles
2. Channels
3. Structures

Well, you need to work with dynamic URLs and Twig to show your sections at Web Page.

Here is the link of official documentation of Craft CMS:

https://craftcms.com/docs/2.x/sections-and-entries.html#sections

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like you're ready to start hooking up front-end HTML templates to the data you've defined in the Control Panel.

The front-end templating section of the docs sounds like where you should start.

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/

Here are some other learning resources you might find useful as you're getting into Craft:

*Craft Official Docs & Support:*

- Craft CMS docs - The official [Craft CMS documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/)
- Craft Commerce docs - The official [Craft Commerce documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/)
- Support Services - Both free and paid first party [support options](https://craftcms.com/support-services).
- Craft Discord group - The Craft development team is in [Discord](https://craftcms.com/discord) every day along with thousands of other Craft developers and users from all over the world.
- Craft Stack Exchange - The best place to ask "how do I" type questions. Our development team monitors [Craft Stack Exchange](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/) on a regular basis.

*Learn Craft:*

- CraftQuest - [CraftQuest](https://craftquest.io/) is our official education and training partner. They have a number of excellent free and paid resources for Craft CMS & Craft Commerce. Ryan Irelan, Mijingo's founder, also offers customized training online or on-site.
- [Tuts+ Tutorials](https://tutsplus.com/courses/search/Craft+CMS) - Not official but [very good and low cost].
- [nystudio107 Blog](https://nystudio107.com/blog) — Andrew Welch is one of the best Craft developers around and the creator of the popular [SEOmatic plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/seomatic). He regularly posts some excellent developer-oriented posts on Craft and web development.

Comment: Thank you Brad. These tutorials are very helpful